# Tool for detecting AI Generated code?

Tags: chatgpt, gpt-3

Can you recommend any tools for detecting AI generated **code**? I am aware of AI-generated text detectors such as [ZeroGPT](https://www.zerogpt.com) and [OpenAI-Classifier](https://platform.openai.com/ai-text-classifier), but I am specifically interested in detecting **AI-generated code**. As of now, I have not been able to find any publicly available tools for this purpose.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or recommendations on available tools or methods for detecting AI-generated code. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi @Haseeb Mir, and welcome to AI Stack Exchange! This question may not be considered on-topic for this site since it is asking about specific software recommendations. It might be better suited for Software Recommendations Stack Exchange. If you have the time, please look at the on-topic [page](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for AI Stack Exchange to determine if your question is on-topic or not. Thank you for posting, and we hope to see more of your questions soon!